# Java-like code (maps, function pointers)

Tags: java, interface, hashmap, function-pointers

I need to do something similar to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef char (*intfunction)() ;

char a(){
    return 'a';
}

char b(){
    return 'b';
}

int main() {

map<char, intfunction> mapita;

mapita['a'] = &a;
mapita['b'] = &b;

cout << mapita['a']()
     << mapita['b']();

return 0;

}
```

As a matter of fact, I don't really have to much knowledge in Java, so I'm searching for some help with this.

Is there any possible way to simulate or do the same as the code above? I was seeing some examples with interfaces and so on, but couldn't make it work the same way.

Comment: [Yes, Java has `Map`s.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: @Makoto I'm aware of that. I'm actually concern about the pointer function part.

Comment: you mean the pointing to a function?

Comment: Well, functions aren't first-class citizens in Java (unless you use a specific function class from either Java 8's `java.util.Function` or Guava), so you can't get *exactly* what you want.

Comment: @Makoto in fact pre-java-8 has `Callable` and `Runnable` in it's core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to use OOP solution to implement the behavior you want.

#### IDEA

As your code illustrates that you want to call different method accorrding to different key.
This scene perfectly matches the *Factory Design Pattern*, So i create a factory returning the method instance based on the key passed in. Then i abstract the *function* to a interface *BaseMethod*. Then, you can create classes implementing the interface to achieve the same method signature when your business growing.

#### Need to be improve

1. the factory is not thread safe.
2. the interface, classes need to be in multiple files.

#### Code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


interface BaseMethod {
  public void run();
}

class HelloWoldMethod implements BaseMethod {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }

}

class MethodFactory {
  private static MethodFactory ins = null;
  private final static Map<String, BaseMethod> map = new HashMap<String, BaseMethod>();

  private MethodFactory() {
    map.put("hello", new HelloWoldMethod());
  }

  public static BaseMethod getMethod(String key) {
    if (null == ins) {
      ins = new MethodFactory();
    }
    return map.get(key);
  }
}


public class Test {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    BaseMethod ins = MethodFactory.getMethod("hello");
    if (null != ins) {
      ins.run();

    } else {
      System.out.println("no method found");

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test2 {
    interface Test {
        public String method();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] arg) {
        final Map<String, Test> map = new HashMap<String, Test>();

        map.put("a", new Test() {
            @Override
            public String method() {
                return "aaa";
            }
        });
        map.put("b", new Test() {
            @Override
            public String method() {
                return "bbb";
            }
        });

        System.out.println(map.get("a").method());
        System.out.println(map.get("b").method());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your code example, but I submitted an edit for clarity of what an interface is and what it is used for. I think it's important for future potential passerby's of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only real potential solution I can think of would be a map of runnable objects:

```
public void doSomething() {...}

//elsewheres
Map<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
//Java 7
map.put("test", new Runnable() { doSomething(); });
//Java 8
map.put("test", () -> { doSomething(); });
```

Either that, or a class that implements a common interface for your object (if you need some returned value).

Answer (score 0):

the syntax might be a bit off, but

```
import java.utils.HashMap;


class CharHolder {
    private char myChar;

    CharHolder( char someChar ) {
        myChar = someChar;
    }

    char getChar() {
        return myChar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Character, CharHolder> mapita = new HashMap<>();
        mapita.put( 'a', new CharHolder('a') );
        mapita.put( 'b', new CharHolder('b') );
        System.out.println( mapita.get('a').getChar() + " " + mapita.get('b').getChar() );
    }
}
```

the output should be:
a b